# Save Visual Studio 2008 Toolbox Settings

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there a way to save the Toolbox settings in VS2008? I've added a 3rd party set of DLLs to my current project and I don't want to have to load them each time I create a new sln/project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main menu:
Tools -> Improt and Export Settings... -> Export(Import) selected enviroment settings

Select:
General Settings->Toolbox : turn on

Answer (score 1):

Toolbox settings are stored into `C:\Documents and Settings\YOUR_USER_NAME\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\7.1\toolbox.tbd`

This should be shared across all your solutions.

More information available [here](http://stevenharman.net/blog/archive/2006/02/19/ImportExportVS2003Settings.aspx).